# (GNU)Sed: how to replace any character from nth character to nth+10?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to replace characters from 10th to 20th in the string which looks like that:

> 123456789012345678901234567890

So far I've tried:

a)

Works for the 10th character ONLY:
`echo "123456789012345678901234567890"  | sed 's/./X/10'`

b)
Doesn't work on the range:

```
echo "123456789012345678901234567890"  | sed 's/./X/10,20'
echo "123456789012345678901234567890"  | sed 's/./X/10\,20'
echo "123456789012345678901234567890"  | sed 's/./X/\{10,20\}'
echo "123456789012345678901234567890"  | sed 's/./X/\{10\,20\}'
```

Does not work and I get error

> unknown option to `s'

So - the question is - how do I make this to work:

`echo "123456789012345678901234567890"  | sed 's/./X/10,20'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$ sed -r "s/^(.{9})(.{11})/\1XXXXXXXXXX/" <<< 123456789012345678901234567890
123456789XXXXXXXXXX1234567890
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a complex `sed` problem, I could just find this solution:

```
$ sed 's/^\(.\{10\}\)\(.\{10\}\)/\1XXXXXXXXXX/' <<< 123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890XXXXXXXXXX1234567890
```

With `awk` it looks nicer:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {for (i=10;i<=20;i++) $i="X"} {print}'  <<< 123456789012345678901234567890
123456789XXXXXXXXXXX1234567890
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with bash parameter substitution like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
s="123456789012345678901234567890"
l=${s:0:9}      # Extract left part
m=${s:10:11}    # Extract middle part
r=${s:20}       # Extract right part

# Diddle with middle part to your heart's content and re-assemble "$l$m$r" when done   
m=$(sed 's/./X/g' <<<$m)
```

See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for more explanation and examples.

Or, you can do this:

1. transform the row of letters into a column so each is on its own line
2. apply your edits to LINES 10 through 20 (as opposed to characters 10 through 20)
3. transform column of letters back into a row (by deleting linefeeds)

as shown in the one-liner below:

```
    $ echo "123456789012345678901234567890"  | sed "s/\(.\)/\1\n/g" | sed "10,20s/./X/" | tr -d "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, that it looks ugly, but:

```
 echo "123456789012345678901234567890" | \
  sed 's/^\(.\{10\}\).\{10\}\(.*\)/\1XXXXXXXXXX\2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without placing multiple X in sed command:

```
sed -r 's/^(.{9})(.{10,20})(.*)$/\1\n\2\n\3/' | sed -e '2s/./X/g' -e 'N;N;s/\n//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace the *10th* to *20th* characters, inclusive, try:

```
echo 123456789012345678901234567890 | sed 's/\(.\{9\}\).\{11\}/\1XXXXXXXXXX/'
123456789XXXXXXXXXX1234567890
```

With the GNU sed, you can use the `-r` switch to remove most of the backslashes:

```
echo 123456789012345678901234567890 | sed -r 's/(.{9}).{11}/\1XXXXXXXXXX/'
```

Or the naive approach also works here:

```
echo 123456789012345678901234567890 | sed 's/\(.........\).........../\1XXXXXXXXXX/'
```

Comment: Isn't it what I posted?

Comment: @fedorqui: You have an unnecessary `^` and `\(...\)`, and you don't replace the 10th character.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/.\{9\}X\{11\}/!s/\(.\{9\}X*\)./\1X/;ta' file
```

or with a bit of syntactic sugar:

```
sed -r ':a;/.{9}X{11}/!s/(.{9}X*)./\1X/;ta' file
```